# Keypress event not working on Android device

Tags: android, events, ionic-framework, keypress

I have a directive which controls my input value desired formatted or not.

```
directive('validNumber', function(shareDataService) 
 {
      return 
      {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) 
        {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) 
          {
            return;
          }

  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
    if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
        var val = '';
    }
    var clean = val.replace(/[^-0-9\.]/g, '');
          var decimalCheck  = clean.split('.');
    if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1]))
    {
        decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
        clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
    }

    if (val !== clean)
    {
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
      ngModelCtrl.$render();
    }


    return scope.hesapla(clean);
  });

  element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 32) { // space
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 45) { // - key
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
 };
})
```

It's working on browser perfectly but keypress event not working on the device.Tried to inspect device with google chrome but not firing. I also tried keyup or keydown but still not working. How can I get this done?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ionic framework, but on android typing does NOT generate key events-  it generates word at a time input.  unless they're accounting for that in the framework I woudn't expect this to work.

Comment: My numeric validation is working. I think  I need to use this input with this validation instead of using keypress event but dont know how to do it

Answer (score -1):

### Include jQuery Mobile file

What you need to do is just include a jQuery file into your project. A file named jQuery.mobile.js or quite similar (ex. jQuery.ui.js) of any version can help you.

You can download it from : [Download | jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/download/)